# Accessing HDRP Volume in script

Tags: unity, c#

HDRP uses Volume for post processing. I am trying to access this feature in my C# script. I can however access the Depth Of Field attribute, how do I access the Near Blur and Far Blur values?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition;
public class LimitDepthOfField : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public Volume postProcessVolume;
    DepthOfField dof;

    [Range(0.0f, 20f)]
    public float mySliderFloat = 0.10f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start () {

    }

    void ChangeValue() {
            if (postProcessVolume.profile.TryGet<DepthOfField> (out DepthOfField tempB)) {
               dof = tempB;
               dof.farFocusStart = new MinFloatParameter(mySliderFloat, mySliderFloat, true); //Does not work
            }
    }
}
```

[image: DepthOfField]

Answer (score 0):

The 4 properties you want are

- nearFocusStart
- nearFocusEnd
- farFocusStart
- farFocusEnd

If you are in doubt about names of fields or variables, simply click on the class with ctrl + left mouse to open it. You can search for the name you see in the inspector and find the corresponding variable name.

You should set the parameter by the setter

```
dof.nearFocusStart.SetValue(new MinFloatParameter(mySliderFloat, mySliderFloat, true));
```

Comment: Ya i know these but it is not taking physical values. Please see my updated code.

Comment: @Strava does not work can come in many different forms. Try out if you notice a difference with the setter via SetValue